# Cannot run any multiprocessing script in PythonWin

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have updated this question to show my problem in a multiprocessing script that doesn't run from PythonWin (by pressing F5), but runs from command prompt.
My script:-

```
"""
File Name: simple multiprocess example.py
Description:
A very basic multiprocessing script to show the use of daemon.
There are two processes:-
p1 - calls listen() and runs in the background (daemon = True)
p2 - calls write()
"""
import multiprocessing
import time
import sys

def listen():
    p = multiprocessing.current_process()
    p_name = str(p.name)
    pid = str(p.pid)
    while 1:
        print "%s process with PID %s running: %s" % (p_name, pid, time.asctime())
        time.sleep(1)
    print 'Exiting :', p.name, p.pid

def write():
    p = multiprocessing.current_process()
    p_name = str(p.name)
    pid = str(p.pid)
    for x in xrange(3):
        print "%s process with PID %s running: %s" % (p_name, pid, time.asctime())
        time.sleep(1)
    print 'Exiting :', p.name, p.pid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(name='listen', target=listen)
    p1.daemon = True

    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(name='write', target=write)
    p2.daemon = False

    p1.start()

    p2.start()
    time.sleep(7)
```

When I run the above script from PythonWin (by pressing F5), a popup message comes up (with title "Python for Win32") saying "Could not load the file from -c"
where  is my file name with full path.

When I run the same script from command prompt, it seems to run perfectly without any trouble. I get the following output when I run it from command prompt:-

```
s>"simple multiprocess example.py"
listen process with PID 4564 running: Tue Jan 04 09:32:49 2011
write process with PID 3744 running: Tue Jan 04 09:32:49 2011
listen process with PID 4564 running: Tue Jan 04 09:32:50 2011
write process with PID 3744 running: Tue Jan 04 09:32:50 2011
listen process with PID 4564 running: Tue Jan 04 09:32:51 2011
write process with PID 3744 running: Tue Jan 04 09:32:51 2011
listen process with PID 4564 running: Tue Jan 04 09:32:52 2011
Exiting : write 3744
listen process with PID 4564 running: Tue Jan 04 09:32:53 2011
listen process with PID 4564 running: Tue Jan 04 09:32:54 2011
listen process with PID 4564 running: Tue Jan 04 09:32:55 2011
```

I couldn't find anything online related to this problem.
Thanks for the help!!

Amit
P.S:
I am running it on Windows XP, PythonWin, Python 2.6.4v

Answer (score 4):

You need to save the code you want to run in a .py file. multiprocessing does not support execution of code that was merely entered in the interactive mode.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, even if I put those set of codes in a python file and run that python file by pressing F5, I get the same error.

Comment: Make sure that you have the main code in a `if __name__=='__main__'` block. If that doesn't help: post the complete code you are trying to run.

Comment: I have that code in main. I have also updated the question. Please let me know if you get the answer to it?
Thanks,
Amit